# Android Tv is not recognising sent command from android app

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, android-tv, remoteapp, bluetooth-socket

I am able to connect Android TV and Android Phone App using bluetooth socket.

- Step 1 --> Searching device  --> Done
- Step 2 --> Paired device using createbound --> Done
- Step 3 --> Got android tv uuid on chanel 4 and can see chanel 4 that is used for RF_COMM
- Step 5 --> I am trying to send a volume up command by using bluetoothsocket?.outputStream?.write("VolumeUp".toByteArray())
  But there is no action on android tv

I am attaching the code here.

```
if (
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    return
}

Toast.makeText(this, deviceToPair.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()

try {
    val paringRequired = deviceToPair.createBond()
    val value = if (paringRequired) "Haa" else "Na"
    Log.d("Log", "Device name " + deviceToPair.name)
    Log.d("Log", "Device deviceAddress " + deviceToPair.address)
    Log.d("Log", "Device deviceClass " + deviceToPair.bluetoothClass)
    Log.d("Log", "Device bondState " + deviceToPair.bondState)
    Log.d("Log", "Device deviceType " + deviceToPair.type)

    Log.d("Log", deviceToPair.name + " ke Paring ke jarurat hai ho? " + value)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("Log", "Exception while using socket connection : " + e.message)
}

try {
    val uuid = getWorkingUUIDFromDevice(deviceToPair)
    if (uuid != null) {
        val socket = deviceToPair.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid))
        val thread = Thread {
            Thread.sleep(5000) // 5 seconds delay
            socket.connect()
            Log.d("Log", "Socket connect done : ")
            // socket?.outputStream?.write(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
            val commandByte = AnymoteCommand.VOLUME_UP.commandName.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
            Log.d("Log", "Volume up sent : ")

            socket?.outputStream?.write("powerOff".toByteArray())
            Log.d("Log", "Data sending to tv : ")
            val inputStream = socket?.inputStream
            socket?.outputStream?.flush()

            Log.d("Log", "Got data from tv " + inputStream?.read())

            socket.close()
        }
        thread.start()
```

Comment: What API are you using to change the volume on Android/Google TV? also, are you testing on a TV or a dongle?

Comment: What's on the other end of the RFCOMM port on the TV side? If it's your own app, you need to show us some code from that side.

Comment: @NeilTurner I am using RFCOMM

Comment: @JensV No I am assuming tv bluetooth should respond for any communication as like remote control does

Comment: RFCOMM is just a protocol that supports profiles like serial, file transfer and more. Do you have any specific documentation or resources which describe the use of RFCOMM to act as a remote control? With the current information, I can only see that you connect to some random socket on the tv and write some arbitrary data.

Comment: I found some references to the Anymote protocol - which seems is no longer supported on Android TV. See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262046/what-protocol-does-android-tv-remote-use